# Count of true and false per row

Tags: sql, count

I am using Microsoft SQL 2012

I have a table with a Name field, and multiple integer fields.

```
NAME|field1|field2|field3

John|1|2|1

Pat|3|2|1

John|1|1|2
```

What I want is the get the count of all of the columns with 1 and a count of all columns with 2 by NAME.

- 1 = Pass
- 2 = Fail
- 3 = N/A and is to be ignored

I want my results to be like such:

```
NAME|PASS|FAIL|ACCURACY

JOHN|4|2|66.6

PAT|1|1|50.0
```

Each row is for a person and each person can have multiple rows in the table with the scores for each field. The first answer is close to what I was looking for except it does not group by person. I have never tried this before and did not know where to start.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Which DBMS? SQL dialects are not all the same.

Comment: This would be really easy with a proper database design where you have the values in separate rows rather than in separate columns. Consider changing your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use several `CASE` for each field, or `IIF` if available in your database

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bbd0/4)**

**Update after question edit** because you use SQL Server now I use CTE to make it clear

```
With field_group as (
    SELECT NAME, 
           CASE field1 WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE field2 WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE field3 WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Pass,

           CASE field1 WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE field2 WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE field3 WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Fail
     FROM Table1
),
name_total as (
    SELECT NAME, SUM(Pass) pass, SUM(Fail) as fail
    FROM field_group
    GROUP BY NAME
)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN (pass + fail) > 0 THEN pass * 1.0 / (pass + fail)
       END as Accurancy
FROM name_total;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| NAME | pass | fail |      Accurancy |
|------|------|------|----------------|
| John |    4 |    2 | 0.666666666666 |
|  Pat |    1 |    1 |            0.5 |
```

In sql 2012 you can use something like this instead

```
SELECT ID, 
       IIF( field1 = 1, 1, 0) +
       IIF( field2 = 1, 1, 0) +
       IIF( field3 = 1, 1, 0) AS PASS,
       IIF( field1 = 2, 1, 0) +
       IIF( field2 = 2, 1, 0) +
       IIF( field3 = 2, 1, 0) AS FAIL
 FROM Table1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for except when it is not 1 it shows a zero. Example, if I have 2 passes and 1 Fail, will show 0. If I have 3 passes and 0 fails, it shows 1.

Comment: check my update. Have to include `*1.0`  to convert integer to float to solve the 0 issue.

Comment: Thank you. Will the IIF account for more than 10 statements? the case statements is limited to 10 nested statements.

Comment: dont know what you mean, for this you dont need nested statement